# Format of number when saved as ascii in matlab is alway scientific? Can it be changed?

Tags: matlab, octave

I have a 2x8 variable/matrix like:

```
25.0000   50.0000   75.0000  100.0000  125.0000  150.0000  175.0000  200.0000
1.0039    0.9947    0.9816    0.9655    0.9467    0.9254    0.9015    0.8749
```

When I save (-ascii ***.dat *** ) it is saved in scientific notation always. ie,

```
2.5000000e+001  5.0000000e+001  7.5000000e+001  1.0000000e+002  1.2500000e+002  1.5000000e+002  1.7500000e+002  2.0000000e+002  
1.0039195e+000  9.9468202e-001  9.8160438e-001  9.6546723e-001  9.4666296e-001  9.2535026e-001  9.0150633e-001  8.7493220e-001
```

No way I am able to change it using `sprintf` or `num2str`. I want it to be saved in ascii file like it is displayed but When saved as ascii it always goes to scientific notation. Am I missing something?

Comment: What do u use for saving? [dlmwrite](http://goo.gl/NokHp) or something else?

Comment: I use save -ascii file_name variable_name. not using dlmwwrite.

Comment: dlmwrite solves the problem. Thanks a lot. Idid not check this possibility.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like it can NOT be done using `save`. use `dlmwrite` or `fprintf` as more flexible alternatives

http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/newsreader/view_thread/240105

Comment: One more thing. dlmwrite write the second row with the asked precision but it removes decimal point as well as the zero after the decimal in the first row, ie it converts it to integer where I wan it to be real. when I use dlmwrite('----',---,'precision',6) I get following 25,50,75,100,125,150,175,200,225,250,275,290,300,310,325,350
1.00392,0.994682,0.981604,0.965467,0.946663,0.92535,0.901506,0.874932,0.845218,0.811645,0.772957,0.746364,0.726704,0.704988,0.666818,0.0956287
Where i want it to be 25.0 or even 25.000000. Why is it so?

Comment: Look at example 2 of the docs: http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/dlmwrite.html, you should be using `.6f` as your precision string.